# Fileupload not working on build Error 500 (Nextjs app Router, Cloudinary)

Tags: javascript, post, next.js, cloudinary

I am using this cloudinary function in my nextjs project:

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import prisma from '@/config/PrismaClient';


cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
})

export const POST = async (request: NextRequest, props: any) => {
    const { params } = props;
    const { userId } = params
    const data = await request.formData();
    const image = data.get('posterImage') as File
    const genre = data.get('genres') as string
    const review = data.get('review') as string
    const name = data.get('name') as string
    const score = data.get('score') as string

    try {

        const session = await getSession();

        if (!session) {

            return NextResponse.json('Unauthorized', { status: 401 })
        }

        if (!image) {
            return NextResponse.json("Image not found", { status: 404 })
        }
        const bytes = await image.arrayBuffer()
        const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes)

        if (!bytes || !buffer) {
            return NextResponse.json("Buffer failed", { status: 404 })
        }

        const upload: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

           
            cloudinary.uploader
                .upload_stream({ folder: 'movie-uploads', upload_preset: 'movie-uploads' }, (err, result) => {
                   
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(err);

                    }
                    console.log('Upload Result:', result);
                    resolve(result);
                   
                    NextResponse.json('Success')
                })

                .end(buffer);
        })

        if (!upload) {
            return NextResponse.json('Error in upload', { status: 404 });
        }
        const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                nickname: userId
            }
        })
        if (!user) {
            return NextResponse.json('User not found', { status: 404 });
        }
        const genreId = await prisma.genre.findFirst({
            where: {
                name: genre
            }
        })
        if (!genreId) {
            return NextResponse.json('Genre not found', { status: 404 });
        }
        const newMovie = await prisma.movie.create({
            data: {
                User: { connect: { id: user.id } },
                poster_image: upload.secure_url,
                poster_image_id: upload.public_id,
                name: name,
                score: parseInt(score),
                critique: review,
                Genre: { connect: { id: genreId?.id } }
            }
        })
        if (!newMovie) {
            return NextResponse.json('Error', { status: 200 });
        }
        return NextResponse.json('Ok', { status: 200 });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return NextResponse.json('Error in the code', { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

This works on dev. But not on production.

Console.log of the error gives me 'Server return invalid JSON response. Status Code 500. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON'.

Console log of result returns 'undefined'.

Page is deployed in vercel, but the upload of movies wont work: moviehub-nextjs.vercel.app

.env variables are ok.

All the other functions such as DELETE from cloudinary work, POST userdata works, PUT moviedata works

Comment: With Cloudinary status code 500 will return HTML instead of JSON in the payload.
I recommend to check the whole request request and response for both headers and body and provide that result by reaching out their support team

Comment: Can you output the `cloud_name` after `cloudinary.config` before `export const POST`? 
Example: `console.log(cloudinary.config().cloud_name);`.
If it's `undefined`, that means somehow the env variables weren't picked up.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?. i am facing the same issue